# How to update the Outliner after creating a material from the Python API?

Tags: python, outliner

I noticed that the call to `bpy.data.materials.new(name="hi")` doesn't immediately show up in the Outliner unless the material is used somewhere.

Can I update the outliner from the Python interface?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "sidebar"? They should be listed in *Material Properties* when you click on the material icon drop down (*"Browse Material to be linked"*).

Comment: Well in my Scripting tab there's a bar on the side. It has a list of "Materials" and it doesn't show up there, or anywhere else. [Here](https://imgur.com/a/L26KNWF)'s a screenshot that's supposed to list a material called "test" that I just tried to create with script #1

Comment: The "sidebar" you're referring to is the [outliner](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/outliner/index.html) with the [mode set to blend-file](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/outliner/interface.html#display-mode).

Comment: I see what you mean, the outliner doesn't immediately update upon material creation.

Comment: Yea that's what I thought first, but try saving your blend file after creating the material and opening the blend file again, for me the created material was not there.

Comment: That is unrelated though, if the material is not assigned to an object and doesn't have a fake user, it is not saved.

Comment: Alright, thanks, then is there isn't really an issue as I will always use my materials from inside the Python script, I was just worried it wasn't being created